# Image is not saving into the defined folder

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am now troubling with this small error. I have a module which is using to upload images. Now this is my code for saving the file. It is defined in saveAction() method of controller.

```
 <?php
 /*rest part*/
 $postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
 if(isset($_FILES['banner_img_1']['name']) and (file_exists($_FILES['banner_img_1']['tmp_name']))) 
 {
     try 
     {
     $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('banner_img_1');           $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png')); 

     $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
     $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
     $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'banner' . DS ;
     $uploader->save($path, $_FILES['banner_img_1']['name']);
     $postData['banner_img_1'] = $_FILES['banner_img_1']['name'];
     }
     catch(Exception $e) 
     {

     }
 }
 else 
 {       
     if(isset($postData['banner_img_1']['delete']) && 
        $postData['banner_img_1']['delete'] == 1)
            $postData['image_main'] = '';
     else
            unset($postData['banner_img_1']);
 }
```

However this is not storing my image in media/banner folder. When I use path as

```
 <?php
     $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS ;
```

it saves image in media folder. I dont know the reason why it happens like this. when I print the $path variable, it currectly points towards media/banner folder. What is the error in my code? Please help me to solve this minor error. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code in the try block {}

```
$path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'banner' . DS .'banner'.DS;
$uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('banner_img_1');
$uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','png','gif'));
$uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
$uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
$destFile = $path.$_FILES['banner_img_1']['name'];
$filename = $uploader->getNewFileName($destFile);
$uploader->save($path, $filename);
$post_data['banner_img_1']='banner/banner/'.$filename;
```

Comment: please check media folder has 777 permission

Comment: now its working. Is there any chance for cache issues during uploading an image?